# How to simulate bad backup file with 'ultraedit'

Tags: sql-server, backup

I want to simulate bad backup file with `ultreadit`, but I don't know how as I know nothing about `ultreadit`. Please help me with that.

I simply want to make the SSMS fail to read the pages of a bad file.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need **UltrEdit** to *destroy* a backup file.
Actually, this really powerful text editor will allow you to nose around inside a backup file and even save it *without* rendering the file completely unusable ...

**Not that you *should***, obviously.

Good old **Notepad** is far more capable of causing this sort of damage.

Just open [a copy of] a Backup file and save it again.  Mischief Managed.

Notepad's *lack* of acknowledgement of Operating Systems other than Windows - and the line endings that they use - will cause it to rewrite the file with extra characters that make its contents complete nonsense to Sql Server.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use an editor to corrupt a backup file. You can use a PowerShell script like the example below to write binary zeros at the beginning of the file to corrupt file header.

```
$backupFile = New-Object System.IO.FileStream("E:\Backups\AdventureWorks.bak", [System.IO.FileMode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Write)
$garbage = New-Object System.Byte[] 100
$backupFile.Write($garbage, 0, $garbage.Length)
$backupFile.Close()
```

Similarly, you can write garbage at a greater offset into the file using `Seek` corrupt data/structures, to cause other errors:

```
$backupFile = New-Object System.IO.FileStream("E:\Backups\AdventureWorks.bak", [System.IO.FileMode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Write)
$backupFile.Seek(1024000, [System.IO.SeekOrigin]::Begin)
$garbage = New-Object System.Byte[] 100
$backupFile.Write($garbage, 0, $garbage.Length)
$backupFile.Close()
```